# Oracle Database - EXECUTE IMMEDIATE inside dbms_parallel_execute

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I've faced the following task: to parallel some process on Oracle 12c database. As always, I've started making this using `dbms_parallel_execute` package. Created a new task using `dbms_parallel_execute.run_task` procedure and passed my anonymous block with stored procedure call as `sql_stmt` parameter.

```
l_sql := 'BEGIN my_procedure(:start_id, :end_id); END;';
dbms_parallel_execute.run_task
(
    task_name => l_task_name,
    sql_stmt => l_sql,
    language_flag => dbms_sql.native,
    parallel_level => l_parallel_level
);
```

This stored procedure calls a couple of other procedures.

As a result, my "parent" procedure fails with the following exception:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "." to continue.
```

As I found out, this exception throws because of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` call inside on of the procedures:

```
l_sql := 'BEGIN ' || some_another_pkg.schema_name || '.some_pkg.some_procedure(:1, :2); END;'

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql 
USING l_param_1, l_param_2l
```

Where `schema_name` is a global variable of VARCHAR2(30) inside `some_another_pkg` package.

When I changed it to a forward procedure call, exception disappeared. But I can't replace this `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on a target environment.

Are there any workarounds to fix this issue without replacing `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please print out the exact value of l_sql before calling execute immediate on it and post a [mcve] thanks.

Comment: what is `get_package` variable?

Comment: Not enough info to really help solve this, but from what you have presented, do you have a semi-colon at the end of your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, my bad, added some changes into my question. 
`l_sql` variable concatenates using a global variable in another package.

Comment: @TenG, yes, this a part of existing code and it works fine, but fails if it runs inside parallel execution.

Comment: Oh. It was really silly. `some_another_pkg.schema_name` was a real problem, because it initializes for session and I try to access it with another one. So it's really `NULL` values. Problem fixed. Can someone post an answer for me to accept it?
Sorry that i've disturbed you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as it was mentioned in comments, was in `some_another_pkg.schema_name` code. In my case this value was `NULL`.